# Ошибка при обращении к элементу QVector

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Есть строка в коде:

```
QString temp_str = TList->at(0).Get_QString();
```

где `TList — QVector<T>`, `Get_QString()` — метод, возвращающий `QString`.

Выдаёт ошибку:

> passing 'const T' as 'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

`->` и `.` Поставлены верно. Да и вообще нет особо сомнений в корректности, так как та же строчка прекрасно работает с `std::vector<T>`.

Вопрос в том, почему стоит поменять `std` на `qt` и возникает ошибка?
Что за ошибка вообще?
И, главное, как с ней бороться, и как не допускать?

Comment: метод `Get_QString()` вашего класса не константный, а метод at(0) возвращает константный объект. Компилятор вам написал это напрямую. Вот [пруф](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#at). То есть у объекта, который вам вернёт метод at, вы можете вызывать только константные методы, то есть методы с пометкой `const` в конце, или другими словами методы, не изменяющие сам объект. `std` или `qt` тут не при чём.

Comment: А ещё если вбить ошибку, выдаваемую компилятором, в гугл (я не поленился и вбил), то второй результат в выдаче ведёт на ответ на англоязычном stack overflow. Не ленитесь.

Comment: @vegorov спасибо, ошибку осознал. Но вопрос по поводу стд открытый. Если нужно залить пруф, что с стд эта же самая надпись у меня работает — залью. Просто я проект под кьют переписываю, ктрлЦ ктрлВ и хоп, ошибка. Почему всё же стдвектор это игнорирует?

Comment: так идем сюда https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at и сюда http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#at , смотрим, сравниваем и все стает на свои места

Comment: @KoVadim спасибо, всё понял. Сам не догадался посмотрть..

Comment: @МихаилКраев документацию читать надо, да =) А ещё, если метод `Get_QString` возвращает не `const QString&`, то желательно переписать на `const QString&` (если есть такая возможность), а то у вас получается каждый вызов `Get_QString` будет создавать копию строки.  С константной ссылкой можно будет переписать наподобие такого: `const auto& tmp_str = TList->at(0).Get_QString();`